# Laravel event/listener test intermittently failing

Tags: laravel, event-handling, tdd, listener

I have a pretty simple test to check my event increases the count of a video play

```
$video = Video::factory()->create([
            'uuid' => 'xxx',
            'slug' => 'xxx'
        ]);

        $event = new VideoPlayWasStarted($video->vimeo_id);
        $listener = new IncreaseVideoStartedCount;
        $listener->handle($event);

        $this->assertEquals(++$video->started_plays, $video->fresh()->started_plays);
```

in `VideoPlaysWasStarted` class, I pass in the video

```
public $videoId;
    
    public function __construct($videoId)
    {
        $this->videoId = $videoId;
    }
```

and then in the listener `handle` method

```
public function handle(VideoPlayWasStarted $event)
    {
        $video = Video::where('vimeo_id', $event->videoId)->first();
        $video->increaseStartedPlays();
    }
```

however, intermittently in running my tests, `$video` is returning as null resulting in `Error : Call to a member function increaseStartedPlays() on null`

What am I missing?

Comment: That suggests it is not finding the video in the database as expected.  Are you certain the factory() call isn't failing? Can you reliably dump($video); after it is inserted and see the expected data? Are there any model events or anything which might be altering or removing the video from the database after it is created?

Comment: yeah, if I dump `$video` after the create, it shows the model, that it's intermittent is what's bugging me. This is being triggered by JavaScript on the front end by snagging the `vimeo_id` - might see if we can change that to get the model instead.

Comment: how does the vimeo_id get set, and is there any chance it might not get set? You might considering passing the id field and retrieving it from the database by that instead.

Comment: it comes from the model. I've just figured out why it intermittently fails  . I forgot about the scope I have on the model that checks `is_published` and the timestamp as to whether it should be available. The test was correct in its failure because a video not published, should not be available. Thanks for rubber ducking James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue here was that I'd forgotten about the scope I had applied to the model to check the published status of the video.

My video factory was setup to randomly assign the `is_published` flag to true/false. So of course, some times if the Video was not published, then the event listener was getting that null result on lookup.

The resolution was to override the factory creation and also improve my test

```php
/** @test */
    public function when_a_user_starts_a_published_video_it_increments_the_start_count_by_one()
    {
        $video = Video::factory()->create([
            'is_published' => 1,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);

        $event = new VideoPlayWasStarted($video->vimeo_id);
        $listener = new IncreaseVideoStartedCount;
        $listener->handle($event);

        $this->assertEquals($video->started_plays + 1, $video->fresh()->started_plays);
    }
```